# Navigation Drawer after a while , keep closing on touch everywhere of screen

Tags: java, android, navigation, navigation-drawer, drawer

The problem is after a while of using app if user open Navigation Drawer and touch anywhere even Navigation Drawer s items the Navigation Drawer keep closing and touch event dost work it happens on random times so i can't use debug. Can anyone please help me on this i have no idea why it s happening

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    try {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();


        if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

            try {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                // change the type of data you need to share,
                //for image use "image/*"
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://cafebazaar.ir/app/com.example.mj.darkchat/?l=fa");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        } else if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

            Intent setting = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Setting.class);
            startActivity(setting);

        } else if (id == R.id.action_change_story) {
            onAllStorysRequested();

        }


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("optionSelected", "problem is option one : " + e);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many test I realized why this problem happened the problem is in my xml I set a view after NavigationView and set that view s visibility to gone so first run every thing is ok but when i set that view s visibility visible whit code for notify user something and after user notified set that view s visibility gone whit code again then NavigationView going crazy and touch event don't response

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/bg_drower"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" >
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


<View
    android:id="@+id/correct_answer_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/green"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

for fix I changed the code like this and set that view before NavigationView and i dont know why but problem resolved.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/correct_answer_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/green"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/bg_drower"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" >


</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're getting into a state where int id = item.getItemId(); returns an unexpected value and your logic checking for id values fails so the code falls through to the close drawer code no matter where you click. Likely, the id field ends up being zero for all MenuItems for some reason.

It looks like some menu clicks launch a new activity, probably when you come back after launching the new activity or backgrounding the app and returning, the MenuItem objects lose their itemId values.

Recommend you add some debug logging or set a break point and monitor the id values you're getting back.  Also add a final else clause so you can see unexpected menuItem values.  ie.:

```
...
} else if (id == R.id.action_change_story) {
    onAllStorysRequested();
} else {
    Log.e("optionSelected", "Unexpected MenuItem.id value : " + id);
}
```